# Problem with docker while using compose up due to pip

Tags: python-3.x, api, docker, pip

Im working on a Dockerfile with the following code

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
COPY . /web
WORKDIR /web/api
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

My code works fine but im having the following error while using **docker-compose up --build**,

```
Step 4/8 : RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 99f13c64bc5d
Error loading shared library libpython3.4m.so.1.0: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/pip)
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/pip: _Py_char2wchar: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/pip: _PyMem_RawStrdup: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/pip: PyMem_RawMalloc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/pip: Py_Main: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/pip: PyMem_RawFree: symbol not found
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r ./requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Please help me fix this issue.

I have python3, pip installed.

Comment: how about try `pip3` not `pip`

Comment: I guess pip should work because I myself have recently used pip in docker file and not pip3. The problem is with your directory structure I guess. It isn't able to locate the requirements.txt file inside the workdir mentioned in container. Either share the directory structure or give full path for requirements.txt and not relative path. This should work.

Comment: @Mukesh , my directory structure is as , in the api directory i have Dockerfile and requirements.txt

Comment: The problem I feel is that you have all the files in your web directory inside container. I doubt there would be any api directory inside web in the container. I suggest you to go through this docker directory once, you will get to know the entire directory structure: https://github.com/iamjhamukesh/Docker/tree/master/Day7-MYSQL-PYTHON-REDIS-STRUCTURED or rather any other directories in my docker github. All these codes work. Your problem is with directory structure according to me. Try aligning the directory structure according to repo. It might work.

Comment: Also if all the above fails, try changing your workdir to simply /web/ or if there is api directory in your container then you may try /web/api/ as well.DON'T FORGET / after api.  It might work. Let's see.

Answer (score 0):

how about try `pip3` not `pip`

```
pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
```

Comment: I have the same problem yet

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a Linux system then type pip3 rather then pip alone
as i was having the same problem and it worked

```
pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt'
```

Comment: I have the same problem yet